# PNG Document Viewer

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I would like to make an image viewer that can display multiple images in a document format. Basically my web application server right now is sending me an array of base64 png files that I need to display in a viewer that looks like a document. A good example for my requirements would be the following picture:

[image]

Also I should be able to animate the pages by rotating them, moving the page from one place to another or deleting a page by either clicking on the thumbnail or scrolling through the page and performing the necessary action. Currently my frontend imageviewer looks like this:

[image]

Which is mostly for testing purpose but I would prefer it looks more like the first example Image. Is there any library that can help me with this or any suggestion on how to start about it. Any advice would be grateful!.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean display in document format? FYI, this question will be down voted or closed. You need to be more specific.

Comment: I have edited my question. Any help would be helpful. Thank you.